# Have a mandatory property/variable only in specific cases, for specifc sub-clases

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an abstract class with a 'mandatory' property:

```
class PMixin(ABC):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def progressbar_step(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

It is possible to have a mandatory property only in specific cases, and not for all sub-clases.

I use multiple inheritance, so if class A

```
class A(PMixin, B)
```

inherits also from B not to be mandatory, otherwise to be mandatory.

A inherits all from PMixin if is not a subclass of B.

If it inherits also from B, progressbar_step is not necessary.

I can declare: `progressbar_step=None`, in the `PMixin`
and overwrite only if is not inheriting from B, and solve the issue, like

```
class PMixin(ABC):
  progressbar_step = None

class A(PMixin)
  progressbar_step = 5

class A2(PMixin, B)
 ....
```

but I want to get a warning, where is the case to have a value, in example A;
It is just a coding 'safety' mechanism

Comment: is class `B` a subclass of `PMixin`. If it is a sub class just put it before `PMixin` in `class (PMixin, B)`.

Comment: no class B is not a subclass of PMixin

Comment: Should you not have two (base) classes? Or the other way around really provide the interfaces as defined? I am just wondering how much of an abstraction it is, if its interface would be a chameleon with extra heuristics. -> And would it not cause confusion/mistakes later on.

Comment: So in `so if class A inherits also from B not to be mandatory`, what do you want to check if it inherits what from B?

Comment: @ShashankSingh    if isinstance(self, B) ; also I updated the question to explain better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`__init__subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation), made available in Python 3.6.  This is called whenever `PMixin` is subclassed, and we can use it to remove the `abstractmethod` from subclasses that meet our criteria.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class B:
    pass

class PMixin(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def progressbar_step(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        if issubclass(cls, B):
            print('is subclass')
            print(cls.progressbar_step)
            cls.progressbar_step = None

class A(PMixin):  # Will raise error
        pass

class C(PMixin, B):  # No error
    pass
```

If you want the warning when you subclass `PMixin`, rather than when you try to instantiate an object of that subclass, you can check `cls.progressbar_step.__isabstractmethod__` in `__init_subclass__` and raise warnings appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

for python versions that are < 3.6 you can define a custom meta class to `PMixin`:

```
class PMixinMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, names, bases, body):
        klass = super().__new__(mcs, names, bases, body)
        if issubclass(klass, B):  # 'if B in bases' is also ok 
            klass.progressbar_step = None
        return klass
```

however since `ABC` also uses a custom meta class, you will get a metaclass conflict if you define `PMixinMeta` as the meta of `PMixin` and inherit from `ABC`.

so you need to create an intermediate metaclass to resolve the conflict.

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class PMixinAbcMeta(ABCMeta, PMixinMeta):
    pass
```

and then define `PMixinAbcMeta` as the metaclass of `PMixin`

```
from abc import abstractmethod

class PMixin():
    __metaclass__ = PMixinAbcMeta
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def progressbar_step(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

**Note**: you will only get an exception once you initiate (use `__init__`) an instance of a subclass of `PMixin`.

If you want to receive an exception during build time, `PMixinMeta` should look like this:

```
class PMixinMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, names, bases, body):
        klass = super().__new__(mcs, names, bases, body)
        if issubclass(klass, B):
            klass.progressbar_step = None
        else:
            if 'progressbar_step' not in body:
                raise ValueError('must have a progressbar_step method')
        return klass
```

meaning that now this:

```
class A(PMixin):
    pass
```

will raise an exception, and not only this:

```
A()
```